# How to stop further request execution from inside a taglib?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags, taglib

Basically, we want to create a taglib that can possibly forward request execution to another page, similar to `<jsp:forward />`. How can we prevent the rest of the JSP page from executing from within the taglib?

Comment: explain more. it's unclear now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing this in a taglib. Rather do it in a [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) or [Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info), before any bit is been sent to the response. Otherwise you will possible get into `IllegalStateException: response already committed` troubles.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following lines worked quite well:

```
String url = "http://google.com";

response.reset();
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
response.setHeader("Location", url);
response.getWriter().close();
response.getWriter().flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to continue processing the original page after passing control to another you are better off using a redirect rather than a forward.

```
response.sendRedirect("foo.jsp");
```

This will redirect to the new page and stop processing the old one.

However - redirects are only usable if you have not written anything to the response body yet (i.e. not sent any data back to the client).

Comment: This doesn't stop execution of the old jsp page. Please verify using System.out.println("After sendRedirect");